# C# REST API for Sharepoint search document authentication issue

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, sharepoint

I am trying to search sharepoint doc using below code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AppConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {  

            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
             string WebUri= "https://company.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='documentname'";

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "password"))));

            using (client)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(webUri);
                HttpResponseMessage responsemMsgx = httpResponseMessage;
                if (responsemMsgx.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.Writeline("responsemMsgx");
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

I am getting 403 forbidden message when i run the program and debug , i think there is a issue in Authentication. Please suggest an authentication method which works.

I have also tried below code ,but it doesn't work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Configuration;

namespace AppConsoleSharePoint
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static string listTitle;

        public static object JToken { get; private set; }

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var webUri = new Uri("https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com");
            const string userName = "XXXXXXXX";
            const string password = "XXXXXX";
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

            object list = GetList(webUri, credentials, "Contacts");
            //print List title
          //  Console.WriteLine(list["Title"]);
        }

        private static object GetList(Uri webUri, SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials, string v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static JToken GetList(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials, string listTitle)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                client.Credentials = credentials;
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json;odata=verbose");
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json;odata=verbose");
                var endpointUri = new Uri(baseUri: webUri, string.Format("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{0}')", listTitle));
                var result = client.DownloadString(endpointUri);
                return JToken.Parse(result)["d"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But,i get error in   return JToken.Parse(result)["d"];
Exception:   Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Parse' and no accessible extension method 'Parse' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)          Active

Please help.

Comment: Use try/catch and get the details of the Exception caught. What's the value of `JToken.Parse(result)["d"];`?

Comment: 401 is authentication issue.. 403 is normally you trying to access a path that doesnt exist or restricted

Comment: @Jawad But i can access the same  url using browser and i get XML response.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes  I am getting syntax error:  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Parse' and no accessible extension method 'Parse' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Program.cs Active

Comment: @AllTech please add the detail of the exception in the question. Also, `result` has some values?

Comment: You are calling the method that says, "Not Implemented". Whats going on there ?

Comment: Yes,i am a beginner in C# , so how to find which methods are available.  methods are not shown in suggestions in visual studio.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes  Due to Syntax Error , i am not getting any value in result. First aim is to avoid the syntax error.

Comment: @AllTech ok. What about `JToken`? Where it comes from?, from Newtonsoft.Json.dll or from where else? and what user Jawad points in its comment: what about the `private static object GetList`?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Not from newtonsoft  ,but declared  as public static object JToken { get; private set; }

Comment: @AllTech and where is the method `Parse` from the `JToken` class? if is in a separate class file, please, add it in your question.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes i am looking for alternative of Parse method or just skip returning anything ,but main issue is authentication . So can you help if we skip the Jtoken.Parse line.

Comment: @AllTech consider check [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) and check code posted there for authentication. I cannot help you further, sorry *(haven't worked with SharePoint in a while)*. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference.

```
string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team";
string userName = "test@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "xxx";
string searchQuery = "/_api/search/query?querytext='documentname IsDocument:True'";

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);

var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential };

Uri uri = new Uri(siteUrl);
handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json;odata=verbose");

var result = client.GetAsync(siteUrl + searchQuery).Result;
var content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(content);
JArray jarr = (JArray)jobj["d"]["query"]["PrimaryQueryResult"]["RelevantResults"]["Table"]["Rows"]["results"];
foreach (JObject j in jarr)
{
    JArray results = (JArray)j["Cells"]["results"];
    var title = "";
    var path = "";
    foreach (JObject r in results)
    {
        if (r["Key"] != null)
        {
            if (r["Key"].ToString() == "Title")
            {
                title = r["Value"].ToString();
            }
            if (r["Key"].ToString() == "Path")
            {
                path = r["Value"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(title + "|" + path);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Hi, i am unable to execute this code ,i got below error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'SharePointApp.SharePointOnlineCredentials' to 'System.Net.ICredentials'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) SharePointApp   Active

Comment: Did you use HttpClient?